# Xamarin Linker removing reference to third party dll

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin-linker

When running my app in Release mode in Xamarin I get the following error with 'Link SDK assemblies only' on:

> /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.targets:
> Error: Error executing task LinkAssemblies: error XA2006: Reference to
> metadata item 'System.IO.Ports.SerialPort' (defined in 'EftPay,
> Version=1.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=e6147cbb02cecb0d')
> from 'EftPay, Version=1.2.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=e6147cbb02cecb0d' could not be resolved. (mPOS)

I am using a third-party library that uses the SerialPort reference in a class (as seen in the error), however, I do not use that specific class. Is there a way I can tell the linker to not strip this reference?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Did you try using PreserveAttribute with your class? Here is a reference, just in case: http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/linking/

Comment: Yes I have tried this without success.

Answer (score 3):

Did you tried to create a static class that "uses" SerialPort class? Something similar to this:
https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/v3/nuspec/DroidContent/LinkerPleaseInclude.cs.pp

Or you could try to LinkSkip that assembly

```
<PropertyGroup>
     <AndroidLinkSkip>Assembly1;Assembly2</AndroidLinkSkip>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: Yes I have attempted this however the System.IO.Port class is not even available in monoandroid so I cannot even declare it. I have also tried the linkskip property and preserve attributes with no success.

Comment: O_o. It seems like that's the case - System.IO.Port is not part of the Monodroid. Check out these links:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5653890/monodroid-lacks-support-for-system-io-ports
https://bugzilla.novell.com/show_bug.cgi?id=687407

My last idea is that you should try to LinkSkip the third party library. If that not helps then you should stick with the "Skip Linking" instead of "Link SDK Assemblies" setting.

Comment: Yeah thanks I have seen most of these posts. I guess I am stuck with no linking. It just creates a massive .apk that is not ideal.